# WindowsForm is moving about 1 pixel when program status was Not Responding

Tags: c#, winforms

WindowsForm is moving about 1 or 2 pixel  when  program status was (Not Responding). But I have to prevent this . I mean, the form must keep its location. How can I do that?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: maybe by moving all the heavy processing you are doing away from the main thread? lol

Comment: Maybe it is better to check why the program is 'Not responding'? I suspect you are doing a heavy task on the main thread of the application?

Comment: I aware of why the form status to be  'Not responding'. Because I send a data package via TCP/IP and otherside of comminucation will send me data. I will done it. But before that I have to solve this problem. I know it is not a big problem, but if I solve it, the program interface will be better.

Comment: that 1/2 pixels movement is just a visual feedback from the OS, telling the user "i got stuck", if doing this is just to disguise that everything is working smoothly, then it is not a good idea.

Comment: The window you see with "Not Responding" in the title bar is *not* your window.  It is the "ghost window", created by the operating system.  It makes an attempt at making it look like yours, that doesn't always pan out perfectly.  I *think* it has something to do with the fat borders on Aero, they are a significant appcompat problem.  There is only one reasonable fix for this, never make your UI thread go catatonic like that.  Use a Thread or BackgroundWorker or Task or Async/Await.